Formula in Chern's Paper Curvatura Integra
I'm currently reading ON THE CURVATURA INTEGRA IN A RIEMANNIAN MANIFOLD  from Chern. And I have trouble to understand the calculation for formula (6). I took the formula for $d\phi_k$ and then I plugged in the formulas
$$ d\omega_{ij}=\Omega_{ij}+\sum\omega_{ik}\wedge\omega_{kj}$$
$$d\Omega_{ij}=\Omega_{ik}\wedge\omega_{kj}-\omega_{ik}\wedge\Omega_{kj},$$
where $\omega_{ij},\Omega_{ij}$ is the connection 1-form or curvature 2-form respectively.
I see how to extract formula (6), but I don't see how the other terms with $\omega_{\alpha \beta}$, for $\alpha,\beta=1,\dots,(n-1)$ cancel.
Can someone give me a hint on how to use the skew-symmetry, to get the desired result. I want to see that
$$\sum \varepsilon_{\alpha_1 ... \alpha_{n-1}}\Omega_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}...\Omega_{\alpha_{2k-1}\alpha_{2k}}\omega_{\alpha_{2k+2}n}...\omega_{\alpha_{n-1}n}(\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_{\alpha_{2k+1}i}\omega_{in})=0,$$
where I suppressed the wedge products. It is clear that for $i=\alpha_{2k+1},...,\alpha_{n-1},n$ is zero.
But for $i=\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{2k}$ I don't see it.

I have not been through this calculation in a number of years, but I will make the following point. When you know that the expression defines a well-defined form on the sphere bundle, you can always choose a frame $e_\alpha$ so that $\omega_{\alpha\beta}$ all vanish at a particular point in the frame bundle. (You can think of this as a version of normal coordinates, but it's easier.) So the terms containing those must amount to $0$. When I have time, I'll try to work it out explicitly for you.
